# Getting avahi to automatically publish CUPS printers

Tags: cups, avahi

I know I can manually add a `.service` file for each printer I have. But I would like to have them published automatically.

But from what I've read, it is also possible to get `CUPS` to inform `avahi` about its printers. (both cups and avahi are compiled with dbus support.)

The printers do not show up (despite marking CUPS to *Share printers connected to this system*). Any recommendations about how to configure either CUPS or Avahi or about how to debug this?

FWIW, I already have `BrowseLocalProtocols all` in cupsd.conf.

CUPS version is 1.5.4, and avahi is 0.6.31.

Comment: I know the mentioned script, but as i understand jcups is using avahi to find any published printers on the net but not to automatically publish it over avahi. But I'm searching for that feature too. If you have any news (cough) I would appreciate it

Comment: Should be working with nowadays' CUPS versions.... (we are now five-an-a-half years in the future :-) )

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [script](https://raw.github.com/tjfontaine/airprint-generate/master/airprint-generate.py) (thanks to Timothy J Fontaine) to generate the service-files via cron and move them to `/etc/avahi/services/` like

```
./airprint-generate.py -d /etc/avahi/services
/etc/init.d/avahi-daemon restart
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is what I meant with `I know I can manually add a .service file for each printer I have.`, what I would like to have is for CUPS to just inform Avahi of its (current) printers without having to resort to a script to create the necessary files. So when using Fontaine's script, if a CUPS printer is created/deleted/renamed, I need to modify Avahi service files to reflect that (instead of having CUPS and Avahi figuring it out themselves).

Comment: Can you check whether Avahi option had been switched ON during build time for your case? Because apparently it is off  https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=188751